# How to keep the highcharts legend "on" while hiding the series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I added some dummy series in the highcharts, but I want them to be invisible at all times, independent of whether I click their legends.

```
series.push({
    name: 'dummyPoint',
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    data: [dummyPointX, dummyPointY],
    visible: false,
    showInLegend: true
})
```

The problem with the above code is that the legends are displayed greyed out by default, and it will display dummies upon the click of legends. How do I prevent it from greying out by default and keep the dummy points invisible at all times?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the `series.events.legend.itemClick` - [Api Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.events.legendItemClick)

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    data: [1, 2.5, 3, 4, 3.2],
    visible: false,
    showInLegend: true,
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function() {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

**edit** : Completly invisible legend
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/n9hat0j6/8/)

Comment: The legend Point 1 is still being greyed out. Is there a way I can prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little trick to achieve it: create a "phantom" series that has no data and **link** the hidden series to it. Legend item will be generated for the phantom series and will serve for the hidden series too. Then disable the default action for this item in `events.legendItemClick`:

```
  series: [{
    // Phantom series - created just to generate legend item
    name: 'Series 1',
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }, {
    data: [3, 0],
    visible: false,
    name: 'Series 1',
    linkedTo: ':previous',
  }, {
    data: [1, 2],
    name: 'Series 2'
  }]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dc4L30zv/

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.events.legendItemClick